# Obtener ultimo ID de varias tablas MYSQL con 1 "columna" en común

Tags: mysql

Tengo por el momento 15 tablas que tienen en común el campo "id_sucursal"

Quiero obtener en 1 sola consulta el Ultimo "ID" de todas las tablas que tengan en comun el id_sucursal, con nombre propio de cada tabla: por ejemplo:

```
id_entradas
id_ticket
id_gastos
```

etc...

He buscado pero no obtengo información al respecto.

Agradezco su ayuda!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Podrías hacer algo como lo siguiente:

```
SELECT MAX(primary_key_column_name_for_table_a) AS last_id, 'table_a_name' AS table_name from table_a
UNION
SELECT MAX(primary_key_column_name_for_table_b) AS last_id, 'table_b_name' AS table_name  from table_b
UNION
SELECT MAX(primary_key_column_name_for_table_c) AS last_id, 'table_c_name' AS table_name  from table_c;
```

Usando esta aproximación tienes la ventaja de que puedes construir la consulta dinámicamente usando los datos contenidos en [information_schema](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/information-schema.html), o en alguna otra fuente.

También puedes crear un procedimiento almacenado que construya la consulta para poder usarlo cuando necesites.

Suerte!

Answer (score 0):

Buenas puedas usar lo siguiente:

He supesto que las tablas se llaman entradas, ticket y gastos.

```
Select en.id as "id_entradas", tc.id as "id_ticket" ,ga.id as "id_gastos" 
from Etradas en inner join Ticket tc on en.id_sucursal= tc.id_sucursal inner join Gastos ga on en.id_sucursal= ga.id_sucursal
```